# How to detect "rotated" images only? (not flipped)

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

The standard object is like this:

[image: Standard Image]

And I'd like to detect **rotated** objects only from this image:

[image]

How can I detect the left-top object only as others are flipped and flopped?

I tried ORB/SURF/SIFT, but it detects too many features.
So just need to detect the ones that the orientation is rotated only.

Cheers.

Comment: If it's only rotated it's bounding box size will remain the same right ?

Comment: @Ziri Yeah, almost same...

Comment: So i think you can easly detect the outer edge and it's minimum rotated rectagle. If your camera is fixed and aligned 90 deg it will work i guess .

Comment: @Ziri 
I just took the left-top part as an example. In fact, the rotated angle is not fixed, so I may have to detect any part regardless of its rotated angle.

Comment: Method 1 : Use the outer edge bounding rotated rectangle Size , if it's only rotated that should remain the same.

Method 2 : Your model image has  3 black circles with known Diameter. detect those in your model and target and then calculate the transformation matrix. 

(you can add more point's if easly detectable).

Comment: @Ziri
Thanks for your patience.
But neither would work as the target object will be ANY one we are seeing in our lives... lol